# How to join USER_TABLES with its corresponding indexes in USER_OBJECTS?

Tags: oracle, indexing, rebuild, user-object

I have for in loop to rebuild indexes of certain tables that have changed primary key.  Anyway to select only indexes of these tables from `USER_OBJECTS` linking with `TABLE_NAME` in `USER_TABLES`, also to exclude any IOT table's index.

```
 FOR r IN (SELECT OBJECT_NAME AS OBJ FORM USER_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'INDEX') LOOP
        l_sql := 'ALTER INDEX '||r.obj||' REBUILD'||'';
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql;
 END LOOP;
```

Above code just simply rebuild all indexes in the schema (included IOT, hence hit error `ORA-28650: Primary index on an IOT cannot be rebuilt`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't use `user_objects` at all; why not go from `user_indexes`, and join that to `user_tables`?

```
select ui.index_name from user_indexes ui
join user_tables ut on ut.table_name = ui.table_name
where ut.iot_type is null
```

So your loop becomes:

```
FOR r IN (
    select ui.index_name from user_indexes ui
    join user_tables ut on ut.table_name = ui.table_name
    where ut.iot_type is null
)
LOOP
    l_sql := 'ALTER INDEX "'||r.index_name||'" REBUILD';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql;
END LOOP;
```

You don't really need `l_sql`, but it might be useful for debugging.

Of course, you need to question why you're rebuilding all the indexes in the first place...

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from user_tables where iot_type is not null;
```

will return index-organized tables.

As I said, when working with *indexes*, consider querying `USER_INDEXES`.